# Has anything changed on geocode API

Tags: google-api, google-geocoder, geocoder

I just wanted to know if anything changed on geocode API from 21 st February because before 21st it was validating zip code 9 digits but from yesterday it is giving an error on 9 digits zip code and now it only validating 5 digits zip code.

Comment: This bug is already reported in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73717905

Comment: @xemonaYes, now this problem resolved by google

Answer (score 0):

More information in your question would be helpful.

I haven't noticed any change, but I thought I'd take a look at the [GeoCoder Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq) FAQ for you.

[image: update date]

Yes, based on that date, I'd say something changed recently.

Perhaps this is what you're referring to, but that's only a speculation since you didn't provide any detail or examples.

> ## Troubleshooting
>
> ***I’m getting more queries that return* `ZERO_RESULTS` *with the new geocoder. What’s going on?***
>   In the new geocoder, **ambiguous, incomplete and badly formatted queries, such as misspelled or nonexistent addresses, are prone to produce `ZERO_RESULTS`**. These queries would typically produce *incorrect* results in the old geocoder, such as returning the suburb if the address could not be found. We believe that returning **`ZERO_RESULTS` is actually a more correct response** in such situations.
>
> If your application deals with user input of addresses, the Place Autocomplete feature in the Places API may produce better quality results. [Place Autocomplete](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) allows users to select from a set of results based on what they’ve typed, which allows users to choose between similarly named results, and to adjust their query if they misspell an address.
>
> If you have an application dealing with ambiguous or incomplete queries or queries that may contain errors, we recommend you use the [Place Autocomplete](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) feature in the Places API rather than the forward geocoder available in the Geocoding API. For more details, see [Best Practices When Geocoding Addresses](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) and the [Address Geocoding in the Google Maps APIs](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) blog post.

---

### More Information:

- [Documentation FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq)
- [Related Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558483)

Comment: Issue tracker is full of bugs that started yesterday, it looks like some internal change on Google side.